# Android App to relocate other Android Apps

Tags: android, file-management

I have an LG Lucid 2 cell phone. It runs Android *4.1.2*. The phone has an internal memory of 8 GB, 4 of which is available for apps. The internal memory is nearly full.

The phone also has a 32 GB flash card which I use to store pictures, music, videos, and documents. The flash card is nearly empty. Google search has many hits on transferring apps from internal memory to the card.

Does anyone have a recommendation that is quick and easy?

**Note**: the App Manager on my phone can only *Force stop* or *Uninstall* or *Clear Data* or *Clear cache*.

Comment: Is your device rooted? Otherwise, I'm afraid, there's no chance. Please see the [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) on our Android sister-site which answers your question. Only few selections possible, mostly only 2: Link2SD and DirectoryBind.

Answer (score 1):

[AppMgr III](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd) should work well for that. I typically just use it to see how much space each of my apps is taking up (because I have a decent size internal storage) but its main function is to move apps to microSD cards. It doesn't say in the app description that your device has to be rooted, and I couldn't tell you off the top of my head if it needs to be or not either. You should try it whether you're rooted or not and post back to let others know if it worked or not. One thing you need to remember is to not move any apps with widgets. The widgets will not work if you do. Also, don't move any apps that you frequently use. It takes most smartphones a minute or so to completely scan and mount the microSD cards so you won't have access to the apps you moved there until it's done with that process. I hope this answers your question and helps. I know it definitely helped me on my older phones especially when I played games that take up several gigs each.

Comment: No problem! Please post back and let others know of your success with it.

Comment: .................I will................

Comment: @Gary'sStudent which Tuesday? Please don't forget us :)